# How do I determine what is asking for a specific submodule in yarn install?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I am running code in node 12. There are plans to upgrade, but this is not an option today. I am trying to do a `yarn install` but somewhere there is some dependency with a dependency of a dependency of `camelcase 7.0.0` but, of course, this is not compatible with node 12. So I get

```
error camelcase@7.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.16". Got "12.22.12"
error Found incompatible module.
```

No yarn.lock is generated, so I can't see what is causing this. Is there a way to see what the yarn dependency tree would be before generating a yarn.lock?

I've tried the following:

```
% yarn why camelcase@7.0.0
yarn why v1.22.19
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "camelcase@7.0.0"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
error We couldn't find a match!
✨  Done in 1.13s.

% yarn install
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error camelcase@7.0.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.16". Got "12.22.12"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: have you tried to copy dependencies from package.json and install same on another folder and inspect that yarn.lock or npm? just to generate a lock file.

Comment: You can downgrade the `camelcase` version in the `package.json` and run the command. It should work. It happens when you are using the package having much higher version that the supported one.